# how to add report filter on pivot in Excel C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

i wanna export pivot table in excel with report filter, i'm currently using EPPLUS but it can not possible with epplus. Please anyone tell which library should i use to export pivot with report filter in excel..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel for pivot tables in Excel using C#.

A code example of using pivot table of the Office.Interop is:

```
PivotTable pt = (PivotTable)activeWorksheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1");
PivotField pf = (PivotField)pt.PivotFields(11);
pf.ClearAllFilters();
```

This article also gives more information about creating pivot tables.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/07/25/creating-a-pivottable-programmatically/